# How to show that the curve $ (x,y,z) = \langle \cos t, \sin t, c\sin t\rangle $ is an ellipse?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, curves

> Show that the curve  $$(x,y,z) = \langle \cos t, \sin t, c\sin t\rangle $$ is an ellipse in the plane it lies on.

$$x^2 + y^2 = (\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2 = 1$$
$$x^2 + (z/c)^2 = (\sin t)^2 + (\cos t)^2 = 1$$
$$\implies x^2 + y^2 = x^2 + (z/c)^2$$
$$\implies y^2 - (z/c)^2 = 0$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + 0 = 1$$
$$\implies x^2 + y^2 + y^2 - (z/c)^2 = 1$$
$$\implies x^2 + 2y^2 - (z/c)^2 = 1$$

This however is an equation for an one sheeted hyperboloid, not a curve. Where did I mess up?

Comment: The best way to write the equation of an ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is using parametric equation. Can you visualize the given curve? It is the intersection of a plane with the vertical cylinder (1 = x^2 + y^2) made from the unit circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is true, however you're forgetting that $z/c=y$. It's kind of like saying $x^2+y^2+(z/c)^2=1$ is an ellipsoid but $x^2+2y^2-(z/c)^2=1$ is a hyperbeloid.

Now, you have:

$x^2+(z/c)^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. Now add the two together and you get your "ellipsoid", but your system is parametrized by $t$ only so it's a curve in 3D which lies on an ellipsoid.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Adding them gives you the equation of an ellipsoid, which isn't a curve...

Comment: You have identified the problem correctly, but it is not an ellipsoid, it is an ellipse.  An ellipse is a one dimensional object, which is appropriate for two equations in three unknowns.  "Add the two together" may be confusing OP-you are suggesting correctly that one take the intersection of the solutions.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think I figured it out. Is this correct: the equation is x^2 + 2y^2 - (z/c)^2 = 1, but only for x and y between -1 and 1 and z between -c and c, because of the range of the sine and cosine functions. Therefore the derived equation is actually only a portion of the hyperboloid, which can be a curve.

Comment: @AlexR. Yes, it is, however your equation isn't a 2 dimensional surface, it's 3 dimensional.

Comment: @sdfsadf: sorry, I definitely obfuscated that point.

Comment: @AlexR. Thanks, I get your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way. Define the following variables:
$$
\begin{align}
\tilde x&=x\\
\tilde y&=y \cos\alpha -z \sin\alpha\\
\tilde z&=-y\sin\alpha +z \cos\alpha
\end{align}$$
with $\alpha=\tan^{-1} (c)$. With these variables, the curve is of the form 
$$(\tilde x, \tilde y, \tilde z)=
\left(\cos t,\frac{\sin t}{\cos\alpha},0\right)=
\left(\cos t,\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{1+c^2}},0\right)$$

Comment: $\cos \alpha = \sqrt{1 + c^2}$?